# pandas Dataframes merge column names with column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': [ 'Hawai', 'Torino', 'Paris'],
                  'Time': [2000, 2001,2002],
                    'Value': [1.2, 2.2,3.4]
                   })
df.set_index(['Location','Time'],inplace=True)


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': [ 'US', 'IT', 'FR'],
                'Unit': [ 'USD', 'EUR', 'EUR'],
                  'Location': [ 'Hawai', 'Torino', 'Paris'],
                  '2000': [666, 888,777],
                    '2002': [44,55,66]
                   })
df2.set_index(['Country','Unit','Location'],inplace=True)
```

It produces this :

```
               Value
Location Time       
Hawai    2000    1.2
Torino   2001    2.2
Paris    2002    3.4
                       2000  2002
Country Unit Location            
US      USD  Hawai      666    44
IT      EUR  Torino     888    55
FR      EUR  Paris      777    66
```

I need to merge them, such as for each country/unit/Location, each column is multiplied by the corresponding value from the first dataframe(given Location and Time)
So the result should look like

```
                       2000  2002
Country Unit Location            
US      USD  Hawai      799.2    149.6
IT      EUR  Torino     1065.6    187
FR      EUR  Paris      932.4    224.4
```

I'm stuck here, thanks for your help

Comment: How do you expect to "merge" the values?

Comment: So you want to merge the dataframes and multiply the `Value`s in dataframe 1  to the corresponding year columns in dataframe 2?

Comment: yes exactly. The challenge here is to merge based on the column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing with `unstack` then `mul`

```
df2.columns=df2.columns.astype(int)
s=df.Value.unstack(fill_value=1)
df2.mul(s)
Out[675]: 
                        2000  2001   2002
Country Unit Location                    
US      USD  Hawai     799.2   NaN   44.0
IT      EUR  Torino    888.0   NaN   55.0
FR      EUR  Paris     777.0   NaN  224.4
```

Base on the comment below

```
df2.mul(df.Value.reset_index('Location',drop=True))
Out[683]: 
                         2000  2001   2002
Country Unit Location                     
US      USD  Hawai      799.2   NaN  149.6
IT      EUR  Torino    1065.6   NaN  187.0
FR      EUR  Paris      932.4   NaN  224.4
```

Comment: Wrong results for year 2000 and 2002

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse he did not show the whole data of df, that is why , and what do you think that number should be ?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse my number show 799.2 and he do not have data for 2000 for Torino so should we keep it same ?

Comment: Based on his example he is using the 1.2 value from year 2000 for Torino and Paris as well. (1.2)x(888)=1065.6 and (1.2)x(777)=932.4

Comment: So my understanding is that location from data frame 1 is irrelevant. Only the year and the value is used. Is this right @Crovish

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Just my 5 cents, Since he did not show data for 2000 of Torino, it make should not  to mul it

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse base on  that idea , the problem become very simple .

Comment: @Crovish `df2.mul(s).dropna(axis=1,thresh =1)`

Comment: very efficient. Thanks Wen.Ben

Comment: @Crovish yw :-) happy coding